# IMG has 0x0 pixels when src added with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image

I was making custom modal popup(#light1). In my JavaScript I take src from the image I clicked on and add it to img tag with id addable.

jQuery

```
var images=$('#raam img'), index=0
$(images).click(function() {
    var src= $(images.eq(index)).attr('src');
    $("#addable").attr('src', src)
    $('#light1').css("display","block")
});
```

And HTML

```
<div id="raam">                
    <img id="pilt1" src="uudistepildid/1.jpg" alt="1">
    <div id="light1" class="wcontent">
        <img id="addable">
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
#addable { 
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px; //even forcing doesn't help
}
```

This all works fine. When I inspect it shows me the right src and sytle with width and height, but it has size 0x0 and I can't change it. It even tells me its natural size. I leave snapshot with the problem.

This is what inspector shows:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlSdR.png]

This is what it looks like( I took out some unnessesay code, just to make it faster to read);

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iDb6.png]

Comment: Would be nice if there is actually some code that you can show us. A demo perhaps?

Comment: I tried to edit it. Tell me if there is something missing, I maybe able to add. Basically it shows only empty wrapper.

Comment: Have you tried to put $('#light1').css("display","block") before adding the src attribute to the img tag?

Comment: This code works. Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/e5c4q/ Your problem is elsewhere..

Comment: Why do you keep wrapping jQuery objects within more jQuery objects?

Comment: @j08691 just started writing jQuery today, doesn't really know better ways jet.

Comment: Where should I look? What could cause this?

Comment: @Riiwo look at the CSS for light1 and addable in the console. I'm sure something is hidden... maybe the image is in an absolute position and not showing in the screen...

Comment: Yep, found it, it took some sytle from #raam img and these were hidden. But why is that? I told him to display block in #addable and I'm only using source? But yeah, I was stuck like hours. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image uses the styles you applied to `#raam img` which sets the image to `visibility:hidden`. When you do `display:block` to show it, it's there physically (I mean you can access it's properties but it's not visible). In order to have it show on screen, you need to set it's `visibility` to `visible`.

Comment: I simply added that to CSS #addable { display:block !important; } works like charm. Thanks again!

Comment: I added !important; to ui-icon in the jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css file.

Answer (score 5):

wow!
It seems that you seem to have installed adblock plus ,close it.
Because your image id name matches its elimination rule "ad***," it considers this to be an advertisement, so it shields your image.